# Is there any practical reason why I must have a code version embedded in python source code?

Tags: python, versioning, setuptools

Is there any practical reason why I must have a code version embedded in the source code?  Explicitly I'm interested in [`setup.py`](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) but also some use `__version__`.  By "embed in source code" I mean must I write the version number in as text in the file rather than populating python fields by other means.

In other languages, I've set up the build scripts to be aware of git tags and then managed version numbers entirely through tags.  This means that there is never a commit in the repo to "bump the version number".  All I have to do is tag the commit for the new version and run the build.

So as a theoretical example I might:

```py
def _get_version()
    command = ['git', 'describe', '--tags', '--match' 'versions/[0-9]*.[0-9]*']
    result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
    return result.replace('-', '+', 1).replace('versions/', '')

setuptools.setup(
    name="example-pkg-YOUR-USERNAME-HERE", # Replace with your own username
    version=_get_version(),
    author="Example Author",
    author_email="author@example.com",
    description="A small example package",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

What's not clear to me is whether or not this would work.  Is the result of `setuptools.setup` parsed before uploading to a package repository or when it's downloaded by a third party?  Of course, the git repo is only available before it's uploaded not when the package downloaded by someone else through pip.

Likewise, am I correct in thinking this would utterly fail to populate if applied to a `__version__` file?

Comment: maybe you could use a github action or equivalent workflow to generate the __verison__.py file, interesting idea

Comment: I thought the build action uses your version to construct the built package file name? And I thought the version info during upload or pip install is extracted from the filename? I don't know, maybe I am wrong?

Comment: You might be interested in [`setuptools_scm`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm) project which automates the version and git tagging stuff. As for having a `__version__` attribute burnt into the source, some people just prefer that simplicity and it is also shown in an example in [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#module-level-dunder-names), which probably helped the popularity. The short answer is that a module level `__version__` attribute for your package is just a common convention, and is not really required at all.

Comment: @wim Yes I think it dates back a little longer.  Prior to modern SCM tools it was common to have a change log in comments at the start of every file.  So *most files* would have the code version written in.  With no compilation, it complicates a topic that would otherwise be handled by interrogating compile-time attributes.  So python seems to have settled on the idea of version numbers in code. :-(

Answer (score 5):

Technically, you don't have to embed the version in your package. Passing the version to [setuptools.setup()](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html) will ensure that it will be save in the package metadata for the packaging mechanism to handle (e.g. setuptools, pip, poetry, etc.).

It has been deemed is a good practice to also include it to the package as it could be useful when you write code which needs to check version of the library (the `__version__` "dundler" is first mentioned in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#module-level-dunder-names) and clarified in [PEP 396](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396)), but it might not be necessary anymore since Python 3.8 embed [importlib.metadata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html):

```py
>>> from importlib.metadata import version
>>> version("wheel")
'0.35.1'
```

So your solution would work fine, but I would recommend you to use [setuptools-scm](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/) instead which will prevent you for managing the subprocess yourself.